# Error with training data and label format OpenCV C++ NDK

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am using the **Android NDK, C++ OpenCV** to train a knn model with 2 images as training data, and 2 labels.

I convert the data to **float and flatten** the data to 1 row and create the labels as shown in the code below.

However I get the error:

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.type() == 5 || samples.type() == 4) in void cv::ml::TrainDataImpl::setData(cv::InputArray, int, cv::InputArray,
```

I can't find any other posts containing this error as their samples.type () seem to equal different values / formats. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

```
AAssetManager *mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);

//Obtain training image 1
AAsset *trainOne = AAssetManager_open(mgr, "train1.jpg", AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
long sizeOfTrainOne = AAsset_getLength(trainOne);
char* bufferTrainOne = (char*)AAsset_getBuffer(trainOne);
std::vector<char> trainOneData(bufferTrainOne, bufferTrainOne + sizeOfTrainOne);
cv::Mat trainOneMat = cv::imdecode(trainOneData, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

//Obtain training image 2
AAsset *trainTwo = AAssetManager_open(mgr, "train2.jpg", AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
long sizeOfTrainTwo = AAsset_getLength(trainTwo);
char* bufferTrainTwo = (char*)AAsset_getBuffer(trainTwo);
std::vector<char> trainTwoData(bufferTrainTwo, bufferTrainTwo + sizeOfTrainTwo);

cv::Mat trainTwoMat = cv::imdecode(trainTwoData, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
trainOneMat.convertTo(float_data, CV_32FC1);
trainTwoMat.convertTo(float_data, CV_32FC1);

//Combine into training Mat
train_data.push_back(trainOneMat.reshape(1,1));
train_data.push_back(trainTwoMat.reshape(1,1));

float labelOne = 1;
float labelTwo = 2;

train_label.push_back(labelOne);
train_label.push_back(labelTwo);

knn->train(train_data, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, train_label);
```

Comment: On which line does your error appear?

Comment: So you convert the data to float with `trainOneMat.convertTo(float_data, CV_32FC1);` and then use the one that is not converted as your data `train_data.push_back(trainOneMat.reshape(1,1));` in this last line you should use `float_data`... Also you convert both mat to the same new matrix.... you use both times `float_data`

Comment: Thank you, very silly mistake.